# How do you append values generated at two different point inside the same for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I am using the manual  method to generate a binary number for the defined   value in the sequence for Eg: ([6,4,2,0]).

The below code writes the high bit (1) for the position mentioned in the input and writes the low bit for position which is not mentioned in the input. For example: `one_bits([6,4,2,0])` will give `1010101`, which means the 6th, 4th, 2nd, and 0th bits are high and rest are low (0).

The below code tends to produce the output in sequence rather that in a row as required (`[1010101]`). Here, the output is generated at two different points in the same for loop. Could any one help me in this?

[Please refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804475/how-do-you-print-the-output-this-6-4-2-0-in-a-single-row-rather-that-sequence).

```
def one_bits(x,lst=None):
    if lst == None:
        toplevel = True
        lst = []
    else:
         toplevel = False
    for i in range(0,x[0]+1):
        if i in x:
            print 1
            lst.append(i)
        else:
             print 0
             lst.append(i)
```

Comment: You don't have to surround text with `"""` when you're posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the output as you specified in your question, or as close as possible to it. Note that whether you use the `bin` function or the functions below, you come out with a `str`(or `str` within a `list`).

```
def one_bits(lst=None):
    return ''.join(['1' if i in lst else '0' for i in range(8)])

>>> print one_bits([6,4,2,0])
'10101010'
```

OR

```
def one_bits(lst=None):
    return [''.join(['1' if i in lst else '0' for i in range(8)])]

>>> print one_bits([6,4,2,0])
['10101010']
```

If you do `int('10101010', 2)` you will see it is `170`

Comment: your codes are working fine.Just a small change in view of range.      return [''.join(['1' if i in lst else '0' for i in range(lst[0]+1)])]  so as to automatically take care of larger values.

Answer (score 2):

```
def one_bits(lst=None):
    return sum(2**i for i in lst)
```

maybe

```
print one_bits([6,4,2,0])
print bin(one_bits([6,4,2,0]))
```